# Find the function $\arcsin(\cos x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Question is from Spivak's Calculus 15-18.  It asks to find the function $\arcsin(\cos x)$.  Answer below:[image]

I have problem with the highlighted part.  If that is true, then why is it our answer for $2k\pi \leq x \leq (2k+1)\pi$ is not the same as for the first case.  Why do we decide to use $\cos(-x')$ instead of just $\cos(x')$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\arcsin(\cos x)=\dfrac\pi2-\arccos(\cos x)$$

Now if $\arccos(\cos x)=y,0\le y\le\pi\  \  \   \  (1)$

and $\cos y=\cos x\implies y=2m\pi\pm x$ where $m$ is any integer such that $(1)$ is complied with.

Comment: Sorry I'm missing the point.  Are you proving that $arcsin(cosx)=\dfrac\pi2 -2m\pi\pm x$?  But how do you know when to choose plus or minus x?  Isn't the above answer better because it gives you the sub domains for which $arcsin(cosx)$ takes on a different value.

Comment: @helios321, As http://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/applications/arcsinxarccosx.html